# tabBarController popToRooTViewControler

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

Every time a user changes a tab, for the selected tab I want to push it to its top level controller. I have implemented the delegate method for the Tabbarcontroller like this:

```
- (void) tabBarControler:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController{
    [[self navigationController] popToRootViewController Animated:NO];  
}
```

This does nto seem to work but I can confirm the method is being called every time I change tabs

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it looks like a simple misspelling.  The correct method is `[[self navigationController] popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]` (you had an extra space).  Also, tabBarController is misspelled, which would prevent the method from being called.

If that doesn't work, it's possible that `[self navigationController]` might be wrong (depending on where you're calling the method from).  If you're calling from your AppDelegate, it should probably be something like `[tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO]`.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Well I did insert a NSLog(@"Hello") statement to check if the method was being called...I'll try the last piece of code you mentioned. Thanks!